# How Do I Update React Component Internal Functions when Mobx-State-Tree Changes State?

Tags: reactjs, mobx-state-tree

I'm attempting to try and update my props when a mobx-state-tree observable map size changes. This is my attempt:

```html
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
    if (this.props.mobxStore.lengthOfEnabledColumns !== prevProps.mobxStore.lengthOfEnabledColumns) {
      this.runThisFunction()
    }

  }
```

However, componentDidUpdate does not detect the changes in mobx-state-tree.

The React component has proper Observer injection.

```html
const connectedComponent = inject('mobxStore')((connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExampleComponent)));
```

The render function also has an observer:

```html
render() {
    const { mobxStore} = this.props;
    return (
                  <Observer>{
                    () =><React.Fragment>
                    <h1>Example</h1>
                    </React.Fragment>
                  }
                  </Observer>
      

    );
  }
}
```

Question: How do I get the React component to recognize a mobx-state-tree change, and run a React.Component function (this.runThisFunction()), outside of the render() block? I'm thinking I could try adding a snapshot or patch, but I don't know how to implement it directly onto the React.Component level function, so it wouldn't be able to listen to React.Component state changes.

Comment: What is `lengthOfEnabledColumns`, is it a pseudo code or an actual prop?

Comment: An actual prop. Returns a number.

Comment: Observer should be on the connected component to be able to listen to changes in componentDidUpdate. Also you can use autorun() or reaction() for detecting change in mobx store. Use them in componentDidMount